# Character Limit on http request for application/json content type

Tags: typescript, http, express, parsing, multipartform-data

I'm receiving a json object containing total 5 fields, one of them is base 64 of image (image size max 150 kb), express server body parser throws entity too large 413 error. what or how should i configure limit of characters in http request? Or should i use multipart formdata as content type.if so how to set it up on server with express and typescript?

I have tried setting the limit of bodyparser JSON to a 100mb.

```
expressApp.use(json({ limit: '100mb' }));
expressApp.use(urlencoded({ limit: '100mb', extended: true, 
parameterLimit: 500000 }));
```

Answer (score 0):

use body parser with limits

```
expressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true ,limit: '50mb'}));
expressApp.use(bodyParser.json({limit:'50mb'}));
```

Comment: those are bodyparser configurations in my code, well i figured out that there was a limit to the http character limit which my request exceeded 30% of the time so i decided to remove image and directly upload to s3. Thanks @Manohar Gavit